# Evaluate the $\int_0^{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi t}2)}dt$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate the definite integral

$$\int_0^{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi t}2)}dt$$

I've been indefinite intervals like this:

$$\int{\frac{\cos x}{\sin ^2x}}dt$$ so I could do this:

$$u=sinx$$

$$du=cosx ....$$

And things would workout, but with:
$$\int_0^{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi t}2)}dt$$
I'm having troubles figuring out what to substitute
$$u=\frac{\pi t}{2}$$
Doesn't seem right because then

$$du=\frac\pi 2$$
And that doesn't fit in my integral anywhere.

**Is this right?**

So
$$\frac{\sin u}{du} $$

$$=\frac{\sin \frac {\pi t} 2}{\frac \pi 2} | f(1) - f(0)$$

$$\frac{\sin \frac {\pi (1)} 2}{\frac \pi 2} - 0$$

$$= \frac 2 \pi$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using subsitution rule.

$$u = \frac{\pi}2 t \text{ and } du = \frac{\pi}2 \, dt \implies \frac 2{\pi} du = dt$$

And since this is a definite integral, change your limits accordingly:
$$u(0)=\frac{\pi}2 \cdot 0=0 \text{ and }u(1)=\frac{\pi}2 \cdot 1=\frac{\pi}2$$

Finally,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \cos\left(\frac {\pi}2 t \right) \, dt&=\frac 2{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos u \, du \\
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

For $a\ne0,$
$$\int \cos at\ dt=\frac{\sin at}a+K$$

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$\int_0^1\cos\left( \frac{\pi t}{2} \right) \, dt.$$

Let 
$$
\begin{align}
u&=\frac{\pi t}{2} \\
\Rightarrow du&=\frac{\pi}{2}\, dt \\
\Rightarrow \frac{2}{\pi}\,du &= dt.
\end{align}
$$

When $t=1$, 
$$u=\frac{\pi \cdot 1}{2}= \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

When $t=0$,

$$u=\frac{\pi \cdot 0}{2}=0.$$

Hence the substitution,

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\cos\left( \frac{\pi t}{2} \right)\, dt &= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(u)\, du \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg[ -\sin(u) \bigg]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}\bigg[ -\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)-\left( -\sin(0) \right) \bigg] \\
&=-\frac{2}{\pi}. 
\end{align}
$$